# I have some problems with React.js states

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am doing some excercises from tutorials on React.js component states. I must do edit, remove and save buttons to the document and textarea. I am trying to do them but my browser shows me an empty screen. My code:

```
<html>
<head>

   <script src = "react-master/../js/react.js"></script>
   <script src = "react-master/../js/react-dom.js"></script>
   <script src = "js/browser.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id = "example"></div>

    <script type = "text/babel">
        var Comment = React.createClass({
            getInitialState: function(){
                return {editing: false}
            },
            edit: function(){
                this.setState({editing: true});
            },
            remove: function(){
                console.log("Removing comments");
            },
            save: function(){
                this.setState({editing: false});
            },
            renderNormal: function(){
                return(
                    <div className = "comment-container">
                        <div className = "comment-text">{this.props.children}</div>
                        <button onClick = {this.edit}>Edit</button>
                        <button onClick = {this.remove}>Remove</button>
                    </div>
                );
            },
            renderForm: function(){
                return(
                    <div className = "comment-container">
                        <teaxtarea defaultValue = {this.props.children}></teaxtarea>
                        <button onClick = {this.save}>Save</button>
                    </div>
                );
            },
            render: function(){
                if (this.state.editing){
                    return this.renderForm;
                }else{
                    return this.renderNormal;
                }
            }
        });
        ReactDOM.render(
            <div className = "board">
                <Comment>Hey now</Comment>  
                <Comment>Hey Anja</Comment> 
                <Comment>Hey Olga</Comment> 
            </div>,
            document.getElementById("example"));
    </script>
```

What kinda mistakes did I make?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is you forgot to call the function, use this:

```
if (this.state.editing){
    return this.renderForm();
}else{
    return this.renderNormal();
}
```

One more thing, i am not sure about the reference you used, Use these it will work:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
```

Check the working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

       <div id = "example"></div>

       <script type = "text/babel">
          var Comment = React.createClass({
            getInitialState: function(){
                return {editing: false}
            },
            edit: function(){
                this.setState({editing: true});
            },
            remove: function(){
                console.log("Removing comments");
            },
            save: function(){
                this.setState({editing: false});
            },
            renderNormal: function(){
                return(
                    <div className = "comment-container">
                        <div className = "comment-text">{this.props.children}</div>
                        <button onClick = {this.edit}>Edit</button>
                        <button onClick = {this.remove}>Remove</button>
                    </div>
                );
            },
            renderForm: function(){
                return(
                    <div className = "comment-container">
                        <teaxtarea defaultValue = {this.props.children}></teaxtarea>
                        <button onClick = {this.save}>Save</button>
                    </div>
                );
            },
            render: function(){
                if (this.state.editing){
                    return this.renderForm();
                }else{
                    return this.renderNormal();
                }
            }
        });
        ReactDOM.render(
            <div className = "board">
                <Comment>Hey now</Comment>  
                <Comment>Hey Anja</Comment> 
                <Comment>Hey Olga</Comment> 
            </div>,
            document.getElementById("example"));
       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a n00b but I figured out the problem in your code :-) Mayank's answer helps... you did forget to call the function by adding the `()` after `renderForm()` and `renderNormal()`

But even with that answer, the textarea still doesn't show up. After 10 minutes of messing with the logic I realized that it's just a typo. You wrote `<teaxtarea>` instead of `<textarea>` ... fix that typo, along with Mayank's solution, and it fixes your app :-)